# I am making a patch-based neural-network reconstructing natural images. But it made dot-patterns that I don't want to get

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, tensorflow, keras

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import image
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import os
from scipy.misc import imread, imresize
import skimage.io
import skimage.transform
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

# Load Training Imgs from Folder
cwd_tr  = os.getcwd()
path_tr = cwd_tr + "/Train400"
valid_exts = [".jpg",".gif",".png",".tga", ".jpeg"]

# print training imgs
print ("%d files in %s" % (len(os.listdir(path_tr)), path_tr))

# Append Training Images and their Names to Lists
imgs_tr = np.empty((400, 180, 180))
for f in range(1, 400):
    imgs_tr[f] = image.imread(path_tr + "/test_%03d.png" % (f))
print ("%d images loaded" % (len(imgs_tr)))

# Load Test Imgs from Folder
cwd_tt = os.getcwd()
path_tt = cwd_tt + "/Train400"

# Print test imgs
print("%d files in %s" % (len(os.listdir(path_tt)), path_tt))

# Append Test Images and their Names to Lists
imgs_tt = np.empty((9, 180, 180))
for f in range(1, 9):
    imgs_tt[f] = image.imread(path_tt + "/test_%03d.png" % (f))
print ("%d images loaded" % (len(imgs_tt)))

print("Type is %s" % (type(imgs_tt)))

# Data normalization and Reshape
x_train = imgs_tr
x_test = imgs_tt
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (len(x_train), 32400))
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (len(x_test), 32400))
patch_train = np.empty((len(x_train) * 400, 81))
patch_test = np.empty((len(x_test) * 400, 81))

# Making Patch
for m in range(1, len(x_train)):
    for n in range(1, 400):
        for p in range(1, 81):
            patch_train[(m - 1) * (400) + n, p] = x_train[m, 81 * (n - 1) + p]

for m in range(1, len(x_test)):
    for n in range(1, 400):
         for p in range(1, 81):
            patch_test[(m - 1) * (400) + n, p] = x_test[m, 81 * (n - 1) + p]

# Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(81, activation='relu', input_dim=81))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(81, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(81, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(81, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Learning
model.fit(patch_train, patch_train,
          nb_epoch=50,
          batch_size=81,
          shuffle=True,
          validation_data=(patch_test, patch_test))

# Results
decoded_imgs = model.predict(patch_test)
recover_test = np.empty((len(x_test), 32400))
for k in range(1, len(x_test)):
    for j in range(1, 400):
        for l in range(1, 81):
            recover_test[k, (j - 1) * 81 + l] = decoded_imgs[(k - 1) * 400 + j, l]

# Print 9 pics
n = 9
for i in range(1, n):
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i)
    plt.imshow(x_test[i].reshape(180, 180))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

    # display reconstruction
    ax = plt.subplot(2, n, i + n)
    plt.imshow(recover_test[i].reshape(180, 180))
    plt.gray()
    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV81B.png)

Hello. I am making a code for neural-network reconstructing natural images. And I am trying to make it patch-based but it made dot-patterns that I don't want to get. I think I made some mistakes in making patches but failed to find what is wrong. So if anyone can find my faults, please help me.